# Does resize image in Java works the same as HTML

Tags: java, image, awt

I've done a research without any result... So in HTML when we display an image and resize them using the `<img>` tag attributes, what happens is that the user will load the original image and then it will be displayed on the desired resized dimension. The problem is that if we have too many images and we use this way to resize image, it will cause performance issues because it can take too much time loading the page with all those resized images.

My question is, in Java when I do something like seen below, will it have the same behavior as HTML?

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(PATH).getImage().getScaledInstance(100, 100, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
```

Comment: Yes. Especially with use of `getScaledInstance()`, see [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](https://web.archive.org/web/20130119065536/http://today.java.net:80/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html).

Comment: Generally, you want to read all your images into Image or BufferedImage instances before or while you're constructing your GUI, and convert the images to ImageIcons when you're writing them to the GUI components.